# Error with adding reference of HtmlAgilityPack to class

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am getting an error while adding this to my class, does somebody know the solution for this?
Using 4.5 framework.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'HtmlAgilityPack, Version=1.4.9.0, Culture=neutral,   PublicKeyToken=bd319b19eaf3b43a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

I have this in my packages.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="HtmlAgilityPack" version="1.4.9.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

packages gives a error that its not declared

I have tried to add it to debug, include it local but nothing seems to make it work

Update:

still same error adjusted it like this, but not sure if correct:

```
<configuration>
<packages>
    <package id="HtmlAgilityPack" version="1.4.9.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="HtmlAgilityPack" publicKeyToken="bd319b19eaf3b43a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.4.5.0-1.4.7.0" newVersion="1.4.9.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
</configuration>
```

Comment: are you using NuGet ? If not please do.

Comment: I did, but have the error, added the assembly from there, but this generates the error

Comment: You may need to manually add an `<assemblyBinding>` for it to your app/web.config file, similar to http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-2550

Comment: @user3763117 that's strange, try to manage NuGet packages for solution and project (right click on solution / project)

Comment: Thay where I got it from, you mean reinstall?

Comment: Error keeps coming back

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it by adding the same assemblyIdentity and bindingRedirect to the web.config (or app.config). Make sure it's in the corresponding place: inside configuration - runtime - assemblyBinding.

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="HtmlAgilityPack" publicKeyToken="bd319b19eaf3b43a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.11.23.0" newVersion="1.11.23.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Hope it helps.